Quantum many-body real time simulation: certain states inner product having no imaginary part?
When simulating the real-time evolution of transverse ising model many-body states, I noticed that some initial states, under the evolution of different times, would produce an inner product that is purely real. This is very non-trivial. Any explanations?
import numpy as np

from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
from qiskit.quantum_info import Pauli, SparsePauliOp

def get_hamiltonian(L, J, h, alpha):

    # List of Hamiltonian terms as 3-tuples containing
    # (1) the Pauli string,
    # (2) the qubit indices corresponding to the Pauli string,
    # (3) the coefficient.
    ZZ_tuples = [("ZZ", [i, i + 1], -J) for i in range(0, L - 1)]
    Z_tuples = [("Z", [i], -h * sin(alpha)) for i in range(0, L)]
    X_tuples = [("X", [i], -h * cos(alpha)) for i in range(0, L)]

    # We create the Hamiltonian as a SparsePauliOp, via the method
    # `from_sparse_list`, and multiply by the interaction term.
    hamiltonian = SparsePauliOp.from_sparse_list([*ZZ_tuples, *Z_tuples, *X_tuples], num_qubits=L)
    return hamiltonian.simplify()

qubit = 5
dtime = 0.2
hamilton = get_hamiltonian(qubit,1,0.5,0)
h_matrix = hamilton.to_matrix()

size = 2**qubit

x = []
y = []

ini_state = Statevector.from_label("00010")
mat = np.zeros((size,size),dtype=complex)


for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
        a = ini_state.evolve(sc.linalg.expm(-1j*i*dtime*h_matrix))
        b = ini_state.evolve(sc.linalg.expm(-1j*j*dtime*h_matrix))
        
        mat[i,j] = np.vdot(a,b)


After the evolution, the state vectors all contain imaginary parts. But inner products magically cancel them out. What did I do wrong?
